# Get a a process window handle by click in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, process, click, hook

At the moment, I can get a list of running processes with a main window using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` and executing a simple LINQ query.

Then, I can import `user32.dll` and the `SetWindowPos` function and I manipulate other processes' window parameters.

Ok, it works. Now I'd like to select a window of a process, let's say calc.exe, by clicking it. In other words, I'd like to obtain a Process object (and then the MainWindowHandle) with a hook that catches the process name when I click on its window.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how this is done in C#, but you have also tagged this question WinAPI so I can help there. In WinAPI, it can be done like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")

int main(void)
{
  /* Hacky loop for proof of concept */
  while(TRUE) {
    Sleep(100);

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F12)) {
      break;
    }

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
      HWND  hwndPt;
      POINT pt;

      if(!GetCursorPos(&pt)) {
        wprintf(L"GetCursorPos failed with %d\n", GetLastError());
        break;
      }

      if((hwndPt = WindowFromPoint(pt)) != NULL) {
        DWORD  dwPID;
        HANDLE hProcess;

        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndPt, &dwPID);

        hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwPID);

        if(hProcess == NULL) {
          wprintf(L"OpenProcess failed with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        } else {
          wchar_t lpFileName[MAX_PATH];
          DWORD   dwSize = _countof(lpFileName);

          QueryFullProcessImageName(hProcess, 0, lpFileName, &dwSize);
          wprintf(L"%s\n", lpFileName);

          CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example result:

[image: result]

In this case, I am simply polling to get the mouse click. A more proper way would be to use some sort of windows hook.

Comment: You probably need to capture the mouse to be able to receive the click on another window.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: `GetAsyncKeyState` can be used for that.

Comment: I'm having some problems getting the cursor position. I'm calling GetCursorPos but I get the X coordinate as something like 6,47208716579385E-312 and the Y coordinate as 0. What's going on?

Comment: @MikeKwan: But if I move the mouse pointer to another window and click on it my application looses focus and doesn't get the mouse click event. That is, unless I have captured the mouse.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: You don't need to capture the mouse for `GetAsyncKeyState` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MikeKwan: Quoting from the question: _Now I'd like to select a window of a process, let's say calc.exe, by clicking it._ Doing that will not generate a click event in your application unless you capture the mouse.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: He can poll `GetAsyncKeyState` for `VK_LBUTTON`. But yes, if OP does not want to poll, then a windows hook can be used.

Comment: @MikeKwan: OK, so maybe it is my mistake to assume that he wants his application to stay in the foreground while the user clicks on another window. If that is not the case then the mouse should not be captured.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: `GetAsyncKeyState` does not require your window to be foreground. See the edit.

Comment: @daliz: I have updated the code in my answer. It might be a better idea to edit the code you have written into your original question because I don't know C#.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for your efforts. But I can't get useful information for my problem from your answer. I know it's my fault.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Kwan said, you'll be better of writing a hook though both approaches have their own drawbacks, but bjarneds already did a good work on this. Have a look @ [DotNET Object Spy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16481/NET-Object-Spy-and-InvokeRemote). It's written in C# and will serve for your needs and more.

You should also note that using hooks are becoming redundant by the day. Depending on what you want to do, other winapis like `GetForegroundWindow` might serve better.